# What is the difference between "funktionieren" "klappen" "laufen" and "wirken"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

In the meaning of "to work" they seem to be used in speaking or writing, but what is the main difference in usage ?
Are there places where one could be used and the other not?

Comment: Please read this: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-about-meaning-translations-or-difference

Answer (score 6):

The differences are not easily covered in an answer here, but I will try to sketch them.

The easiest among them might be *"wirken"*. A better translation here would be *'to have an effect'*, like medicine has an effect on you. Also a method or a treatment can *"wirken"*, or *'work'*, if it actually has an effect. *"Wirken"* can also have various other meanings, that are beyond the scope here I hope.

*"Laufen"* can be translated to *'run'*, not only in the original meaning, but also figuratively. A computer can *'run'*, or *"laufen"*.

It gets a bit more complicated when looking at *"funktionieren"* and *"klappen"*. It is to be noted that *"klappen"*, in the meaning of *"to work"*, is colloquial and never formal. In this meaning *"klappen"* can always be substituted by *"funktionieren"*, but not the other way around.

A computer or a machine can *"funktionieren"*, opposed to being broken or not working propperly. But it can never *"klappen"*.

"*Klappen*" is always used like *'work out'* in the sense of

> Our plan will work out in the end.
>   Unser Plan wird am Ende *klappen*.

If you just omit the usage of *"klappen"* you are better off in the begining.

I hope this helped.